Expo Development Build stuck on splash screen on my physical iOS device

The web version of my react native app works fine.
I am on the same
wifi network.
I have tried to rebuild it to no avail.
Expo go works
completely fine.
I created a new project and it was working
completely fine when I used development build mode.
I have deleted
and redownloaded all my npm packages

Genuinely have looked at almost every post online and haven't found any solution. There are no errors present
$ npx expo start                                                      
Starting project at /home/edes/Asztal/code/St-Pauls-App/StPaulsApp
Starting Metro Bundler
The following packages should be updated for best compatibility with the installed expo version:
  react-native@0.76.3 - expected version: 0.76.5
  react-native-safe-area-context@5.0.0 - expected version: 4.12.0
Your project may not work correctly until you install the expected versions of the packages.
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▄████▄███ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ █ ▀█ ▄ █▄██ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █▄ ▄▄▀██▄▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀▄▀▄█ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█ ▄  █▀▄▀ ▀███▀▀██▄██▄ ▄▀▄█
██ ▄ ▄ ▄▀▄██▀▀ ▄█▀█ ▀██▀███
█▄▄▀  ▀▄▄▄▄▀ █ █▀▄█ ▄ █ █▀█
█▀▄█▀  ▄▀█▄██ ▄██ ▀▀█▀▀█ ▀█
██████▄▄█   ▄▀  ▄ ▄▄▄ ▀▄█▀█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▀█▄ █▀█ █▄█ █▄ ▄█
█ █   █ █▀▀▀▄▀▀▀▀▄▄   █▀▀ █
█ █▄▄▄█ █  ▀▄▄▀▄▀▄▀▄█▄▄ ▄██
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄██▄█▄██████▄▄▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.86.42:8081
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera
app (iOS)

› Web is waiting on http://localhost:8081

› Using Expo Go
› Press s │ switch to development build

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu
› shift+m │ more tools
› Press o │ open project code in your editor

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
iOS Bundled 1238ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (1100 modules)
 (NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled
 INFO  
  JavaScript logs will be removed from Metro in React Native 0.77! Please use React Native DevTools as your default tool. Tip: Type j in the terminal to open (requires Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge).


If you are developing on Mac, a great way to debug this is to prebuild (npx expo prebuild -p ios) and then building and running from Xcode. That way you can see the native logs as well. Do you use any splash screen overrides in your project?

I'm on Debian linux and I don't use any splash screen overrides
